# Odd lighting issue - Unreal

Tags: unreal-engine4, fedora-28

The preview screen in Unreal is showing very jagged shadows on the landscape.
The shadows change direction depending on the position of the viewport.
We tried changing the Preview Rendering Level between SM4 and SM5.
The SM4 shows a large yellow triangle across the screen.
SM5 has the current issue described above.
The Engine Scalability settings are currently set to medium, down from epic with no noticeable difference.
We are running Unreal 4.20.3 on Linux Fedora 28
[image: Lighting Issue - Choppy Shadows]

Comment: Oops, actually its Unreal 4.20.2

Comment: What graphics driver?

Comment: The driver is i915

Answer (score 0):

Increase Static Lighting Resolution in power of 2, like 1,2,4,8..etc, but dont go too high, just check if which value works for you.

also, make sure when you build your light set it to production not preview to see the highest quality available based on your setting.

This may work for you.

Comment: We tried these suggestions but they did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue began after moving the location of Unreal Engine. By creating a new project we found that the issues no longer exist. It may have been a referencing issue of some kind.